# How can I prevent multiple button clicks?

Tags: javascript, html

So, I have something like this in my HTML code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Testing stuff</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick = "increase_var();">Click me to make a variable go higher!</button>
    <script>
      let thing = 0;
      function increase_var()
      {
        thing += 1;
        console.log(thing);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you run this code and hold down the enter key on the button, you'll see the variable going up on it's own, which is not what I want. The desired result is for you to be forced to press enter on the buttons to make the variables go up (the solution must work with multiple buttons, not just this example).
I have tried searching online, but all the problems that were similar to mine had the script reading keyboard input (something which I am not doing).
To reiterate, I wish for a user to be unable to hold down their enter key and have the button events fired at a constant rate. I wish for the user to be forced to press the key every time they wish for something to rise higher

Answer (score 1):

you could use onkeyup as this makes sure that the user releases the button key

Answer (score 0):

you can try it with `onkeyup` event:

```
<button onkeyup = "increase_var();">Click me to make a variable go higher!</button>
```

Comment: The problem with the approach now is that the event fires whenever any key is released (I opened the console one time and the variable increased without me actually activating a button)

Comment: Well then pass an argument `increase_var(event)` then you check if the enter key is pressed in your function `event.keyCode === 13`